# Remove number properties from an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to remove properties that are numbers from an object:

```js
function removeNumberValues(obj) {
  for (i in obj) {
    if (obj['i'] instanceof Number) {
      delete obj['i'];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

But it's not removing numerical properties. Halp? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide a json ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the variable `i`, not the value `'i'`, and you could check with [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) and `number` as value.

```js
function removeNumberValues(object) {
    var key;
    for (key in object) {
        if (typeof object[key] === 'number') {
            delete object[key];
        }
    }
    return object;
}

console.log(removeNumberValues({ a: 'foo', b: 42 }));
```

With [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating the keys.

```js
function removeNumberValues(object) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
        if (typeof object[key] === 'number') {
            delete object[key];
        }
    });
    return object;
}

console.log(removeNumberValues({ a: 'foo', b: 42 }));
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Why can't I use an iterator? I was able to use it for a similar function that would delete a property if it was even.

Comment: If you also want to delete properties which also could have string values of numbers e.g. var obj = {prop1 : "12"}, i would suggest using isNaN() instead of typeof.

Comment: @Advokaten01, the loop is iterating over the object keys. What do you mean?

Comment: @Advokaten01, what do you mean with iterator?

Comment: @NinaScholz I mean instead of just doing it as: for (i in obj). That is, why do I need to define a variable beforehand?

Comment: it spoils the global scope if you use a variable in a function. you could get funny result if you use nested `for` loops with the same `i`. So a good advice is to declare all variables in advance and `use strict` wherever posible.

Comment: You'll often see it as `for (var key in object)` or, in ES6 `for (let key in object)` which will scope the variable to the block rather than the function.

Comment: `var` has no block scope, `let` has.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof` instead. It's more reliable in this case. Unless the value derives from a `Number` constructor it's not gonna work.

```js
const obj = {
  str: "string",
  num: 1,
  str2: "string2",
  num2: 2
};

console.log(removeNumberValues(obj));

function removeNumberValues(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'number') {
      delete obj[key];
    }
  });

  return obj;
}
```